# make an entire div clickable

Tags: jquery, css

Right now I havae a menu, that I'm using jquery to do a fade in and out on mouseenter and leave

this is super basic jsfiddle of the function (loos like hell i know, but you ge the idea)
http://jsfiddle.net/A26d9/2/

So..right now only the text is clickable. How can I make it so the entire div is clickable. I've tried using

```
    $(".home_hover").click(function(){
     window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
     return false;
});
```

but it just dissables the entire menu. I know this is easy. I'm just blank right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it will look for an `a` element inside the `#home` div, and send the browser there on click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home')
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $('.home_hover', $(this)).fadeIn()
        })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            $('.home_hover', $(this)).fadeOut();
        })
        .click(function() {
            var link = $("a", $(this));
            if (link.length) {
                window.location.assign(link.attr("href"));
            }
        });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A26d9/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
$('#home').click(function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this the same way you do to buttons in Jquery. You can give the div a class, or an ID, and then associate an event to the click. For instance, your div has a class of "regDiv"

```
$('.regDiv').live("click", function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
```